# Unable to transform with scale 100%: Error 8007

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

My question is two fold:
Firstly, is this a bug in Photoshop? If you scale a layer and supply values of 100% like so

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{
  var thisLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];

   //select that layer as you go along
   srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];
}
```

It shows the error:
Error 8007: user cancelled the operation

[image: photoshop user cancelled operation error]

Scale values of 100.000001, however are fine.

The second, more important part, even with  displayDialogs switched off

```
 displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF
```

the user is forced to commit transform with enter or the tick button.
Is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: As a guess, a scale of 100% means don't change the scale. If there is no change, Photoshop probably goes to the same else branch in its own code as when the user cancels the resize, and Photoshop displays the dialog. The effect is the same, no change. Not sure abuot the second part, I haven't tried Photoshop scripting.

Comment: Could it be that you have a `Background` layer among the layers of the document? You can't transform it. Otherwise I don't have this warning message when I use a resize with the same arguments as you do (in PS 2020).

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I've already thought of that - I've got a    if (srcDoc.layers[i].isBackgroundLayer == true) check going on at the top of the loop

Comment: What PS version do you use? Regarding your second question, does this happen only when width/height are 100?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiyCC 2018 And I've figured it out now, whilst I had called  displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; I also accidentally uncommented a line of code, prior to the transformation and set it back to normal. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much for a comment so I'll add this as an answer. `User cancelled the operation` error can be helpful sometimes: for example, when you want to show UI and you don't know if user hit OK, Cancel or there was an error. And personally I think that setting a global `displayDialogs` is too much in this case: if something goes wrong a user will stuck with the option you set, not the one they had. In this you can check for error number:

```
try
{
  //some code
}
catch (e)
{
  if (e.number == 8007)
  {
    // do something or ignore
  }
  else
  {
    // an actual error
    alert(e);
  }
}
```